# How to return a link from an MVC controller with return type as "Content"

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I want to return a Content type but the content has one URL in it. Below is my code.

```
public ActionResult Safari() {
    return Content("<html>Click this URL <a href ="https://www.google.com/chrome"</html>");
}
```

I want the link **Google.com** to be rendered as hyperlink and not text. And for some reason I don't want to return a view.cshtml page.

Attempts Made:

```
return Content("<html>Click this URL <a href ="https://www.google.com/chrome"</html>");
return Content(@"<html>Click this URL <a href ="https://www.google.com/chrome"</html>");
return Content("<html>Click this URL <a href =/"https://www.google.com/chrome/"</html>");
```

Other attempts:

```
public ActionResult Safari() {
    return Content("< a href = 'google.com/chrome' > Click this URL </ a > ");
}
```

[image]

Comment: Well, the first and last example aren't properly escaping the quotes. It should be `\"` to escape a quote. So I don't know if that solves the issue. That aside, why not just return a string? In addition, is it possible that the content is being rendered encoded in which case the tags come out as strings?

Comment: The way you're doing it on the second line is fine (but no need for `<html>` and `</html>`). The problem is in the display, so how are you displaying the content on your view? Add that code to your question.

Comment: Yeah, the `html` stuff will break the DOM if inserted into the middle of the page. If replacing everything it would work though, or if starting a new window/tab.

Comment: I just want an empty page with this message and link as hyper link. P.S: I dont want to use view

Comment: @TravisJ: I tried changing to the correct "/" escape sequence and it compiled properly but the entir elink vanished in UI.

Comment: @TravisJ *If replacing everything it would work though*, no it's invalid HTML as the link must be in `<body>`.

Comment: Just a basic page with one message and URL in it. That's all I need.

Comment: If you just want a simple HTML page, then you must provide a valid page HTML with the `<body>` tag.

Comment: @RacilHilan: the attempt you had mentioned did not work. I updated the question with the result.

Comment: Why you have spaces in your tag?

Comment: @RacilHilan - Yeah, you are correct that it doesn't have a body tag. However, some browsers are very lenient and will automatically generate the body.

Comment: @RacilHilan: Silly me. My bad. Your solution mentioned in above comments worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want a simple HTML page, then you must provide a valid page HTML with the `<body>` tag. You can return the link alone without the `<html>` tag like this:

```
return Content("<a href ='https://www.google.com/chrome'>Click this URL</a>");
```

and hope that the browser will add the missing `<html>`, `<head>`, and `<body>` tags to complete your page. All major browsers will do that.

However, it is better to provide a complete HTML code and not worry about the browsers:

```
return Content("<html><head></head><body><a href ='https://www.google.com/chrome'>Click this URL</a></body></html>");
```